# JavaScript - How to set focus to the Popup window

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript is there an option to point focus to an already opened Popup window?

**Scenario:** 
In a web page, I click on a link in webpage1 to open a popup window. Now I want to fill up few details in the popup window using JavaScript followed by save and close the popup window.